# Rendering issues for Fixed Position Youtube embed on Android

Tags: javascript, android, responsive-design, css-position

**I'm having one of the strangest rendering issues with Android browsers** (**Galaxy Tab 10.1 and S3 so far** .. haven't tested on iPhone or other mobile browsers).

**I'm dynamically embedding a fixed position responsive Youtube video on a webpage**. You click a button in Javascript - it creates a black backdrop (also fixed position) and a Youtube embed with an id so I can control the properties at different screen sizes. So far so good. This goes off without a hitch. I check it out in Chrome, Firefox and even IE and I'm not disappointed. Yet.

I check it on my Android phone (Galaxy S3 - stock browser) and **it appears that the video is having a hard time understanding where it's supposed to be rendered**. I notice at least 3 repositions before it settles on a spot. Sometimes I'm lucky to see part of the element is somewhat on screen. Most other times, not so lucky. The code hasn't changed and the browser size definitely hasn't changed; just the rendering has.

To make matters worse, **it seems like the element is actually placed in the correct place but rendered incorrectly**. If I click on the center (or near enough to it), the video plays! The rendering shows it playing while re-rendering constantly, still unsure of where its supposed to be.

I know this problem sounds super-crazy and it might be a tricky one to even diagnose (let alone debug) so I'm including as much code related to the whole operation as possible. Help is greatly appreciated!

**Creating and Embedding the Video**

```
donModal.addEventListener("click", function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        var donPreview = document.createElement("iframe");
        donPreview.src = "http://www.youtube.com/embed/oeZgLFsglcc";
        donPreview.frameborder = "0";
        donPreview.allowfullscreen = "allowfullscreen";
        donPreview.id = "donModalVideo";

        document.body.appendChild(donPreview);

        sfx.toggleBackdrop(donPreview);         
    });
}
```

**Video Styles**

```
#donModalVideo {
  position: fixed;
  width: 40%;
  height: 50%;
  top: 25%;
  left: 30%;
  z-index: 95;
}
```

**URL for Test**

*Can't fiddle right now .. hope this is ok ...*

http://openheavens.designbymobius.ca/artistes#donmoen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved it!!!**

There were a combination of factors that contributed to the problem.

1. There was **no height set** for it (or it's parent element).
2. **Fixed position is glitchy on mobile devices**

Armed with that knowledge, I:

1. Changed the position property to static.
2. Wrote a little function to set the height as a fixed ratio of the width (I used 0.5625) which triggered every time the window was resized. Now the video size is flexible and it perfectly maintains its ratio.
3. Wrote a second function to set the top value as the `(viewport height - video height) / 2` + `window.pageYOffset`. It's triggered whenever you scroll the page.

End result is a static position video which dynamically adjusts width while maintaining its ratio as well as simulates the effect of position: fixed.

The end result can be seen [here](http://openheavenstoronto.com/artistes). Click to watch an artist preview video :)